# Erro undefined utilizando replace()

Tags: javascript, array, regex

Estou tentando fazer uma espécie de marcação de pessoas, fiz uma tentativa, mas não obtive sucesso.
Onde está o erro??

```js
var nome =["Ana", "João", "Maria", "José"];
var frase = "@[1] é casado com @[0], e @[2] é casada com @[3].";

var msg = frase.replace(/@\[(\d)\]/gmi, nome["$1"]);

document.write(msg);
```

O código deveria retornar:

> João é casado com Ana, e Maria é casada com José.

Comment: O que o código está retornando?

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu *"undefined é casado com undefined, e undefined é casada com undefined"...* ;)

Comment: Tenta `var msg = frase.replace(/@\[(\d)\]/gmi, nome[0]);` só pra confirmar que o erro está em ["$1"]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bem, ao escrever `nome["$1"]`, você está passando uma `string` como `index` do seu `array`, e como a posição não existe, `undefined` é retornado para você por padrão. Isso quer dizer que o valor é indefinido.

Assim sendo, todo o restante do seu código está correto, mas para cumprir seu objetivo de mudar o index de acordo com o informado na frase, basta usar uma função anônima da seguinte forma:

```
msg = frase.replace(/@\[(\d)\]/gmi, function(matchedText, $1, offset, str){return nome[$1]})
```

O seu código completo (funcionando) ficaria assim:

```js
var nome =["Ana", "João", "Maria", "José"];
var frase = "@[1] é casado com @[0], e @[2] é casada com @[3].";

msg = frase.replace(/@\[(\d)\]/gmi, function(matchedText, $1, offset, str){return nome[$1]})

document.write(msg);
```

Veja uma pergunta semelhante:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8990209/4720858

Mais sobre o assunto [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/n).